# Can "happen to" be followed by a Present Progressive form?

Tags: infinitive-vs-gerund, to-infinitive, continuous

Or does it always take an infinitive form?

Ex.: Is "I happen to be doing this at the moment" correct or should you say "I happen to do this at the moment"?

Comment: ***To be** doing* is an infinitive form.

Comment: The form of the verb is exactly the same as the sentence without *happen to:* "I happen to be doing X" is the same as "I am doing X" and "I happen to do X" is the same as "I do X". It is a question of differentiating between **at this moment** and **occurring regularly.**

Answer (score 1):

Both are grammatical:

I happen to have her address if you need it.

I happen to be playing pocket billiards again, now that my thumbs have healed.